# Serializing Object to YAML in Java using snakeyaml Library

Tags: java, serialization, snakeyaml

I do not have much experience with Serialization. While trying to serialize a simple object of the class below i get this `No JavaBean properties found exception` from YAML library.

Here is the class:

```
public class MyClass {
    String value;
    public MyClass(String args) {
        value = args;
    }

    public String getValue(){
        return value;
    }
}
```

And here is how i am serializing using SnakeYAMAL:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml;


public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MyClass obj = new MyClass("this is my data");

        Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        data.put("MyClass", obj);
        Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
        String output = yaml.dump(data);
        System.out.println(output);
    }

}
```

and upon executing, this exception is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.yaml.snakeyaml.error.YAMLException: No JavaBean properties found in MyClass
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.introspector.PropertyUtils.getProperties(PropertyUtils.java:112) ...
```

Can you tell me what is it that i am missing in doing this, or how should i do it properly?

EDIT:

```
public class MyClass {
    String value;
    public MyClass() {}

    public String setValue(String value){
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue(){
        return value;
    }
}
```

and if i set the value before serializing it, it somehow works.
Do you think it is proper solution or not a recommended approach?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

SnakeYAML is designed primarily for serializing JavaBeans.

The example you give above does not conform to the JavaBean specification. To be a JavaBean, an object must have a no-argument constructor, and every field must have a getter and a setter.

If you rewrite your class as a bean, SnakeYAML should serialize it with no problems. Also, SnakeYAML can serialize public fields, so you if you change `value`'s visibility to `public` then SnakeYAML will find and serialize it.

If you really want to avoid altering `MyClass`, you can explicitly tell SnakeYAML to serialize read-only properties, something like this:

```
PropertyUtils propUtils = new PropertyUtils();
propUtils.setAllowReadOnlyProperties(true);
Representer repr = new Representer();
repr.setPropertyUtils(propUtils);
Yaml yaml = new Yaml(new Constructor(), repr);
```

However, dumping non-JavaBean objects to YAML may cause problems when you come to de-serialize them back to an `Object`, so I recommend using JavaBeans as the easiest and safest solution.

**Edit:** Here is an example of MyClass converted to a JavaBean:

```
public class MyClass {
    String value;

    /* public, no-argument constructor */
    public MyClass() {
    }

    /* Every field has a public getter... */
    public String getValue(){
        return value;
    }

    /* ... and a public setter */
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add a very small examlpe of transforming this class to JavaBean. I am not sure how to use JavaBeans, thanks

Comment: @Johnydep I've edited my answer to include an example of converting `MyClass` to a valid JavaBean.

Comment: can you confirm if my edited code is the proper way of using YAML serialization? thank you

Comment: Is there a way to make SnakeYAML work with the auto-generated no-arg constructor, getters and setters from Project Lombok?